# Java RMI client exit

Tags: java, for-loop, rmi

I'm currently teaching myself Java and I'm trying to build a Java RMI auction system.

I currently have a number of classes;

```
auctionServer - starts the RMI registry, creates localhost service "AuctionService"
auctionInterface - provides a description of remote methods available as provided by auctionImpl
auctionImpl - implements the RMI interface
auctionBuyer - a client to offer options to bid on items
auctionSeller - a client to offer options to list items on the server
```

What I am struggling with is providing the user with a way to exit the clients whilst keeping the server running.

Here is my server code;

public class auctionServer {

```
public auctionServer() {
    try {
        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        auctionInterface c = new auctionImpl();
        Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost/AuctionService", c);
        System.out.println("Server running.....");
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Server Error: " + e);
        }
    }

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new auctionServer();
}
```

}

At present I have the following method for the seller client inside my auctionImpl;

```
public void sellerChoice(){         
    System.out.println("---- What would you like to do? ----\n");
    System.out.println("1: List an item for auction\n");                    /* Main menu interface */
    System.out.println("2: Print a list of active items\n");
    System.out.println("3: Remove an item from the auction\n");
    System.out.println("4: Close the seller client\n");

    int menuSelection = scanner.nextInt();  // Create switch case
    switch(menuSelection){
        case 1: // If user chose option 1
                listItem();
            break;  
        case 2: // If user chose option 2
                printList();
            break;
        case 3: // If user chose option 3
                removeItem();
            break;
        case 4:
                System.exit(0);
            break;
        default: // If user chose an option other than 1*2*3
            System.out.println("You didn't select 1, 2 or 3!!");
    }       
}
```

As you can imagine System.exit() does not work in the way I want it to here, because it ends not only  the client but the server as well. So I am struggling to find a way to implement a way to exit the seller client without shutting down the server.

Another thing I am struggling with is checking if an auctionID is already in use when creating an item;

```
public void listItem(){
    ItemInfo createdItem = new ItemInfo();

    System.out.println("----Enter the auctionName----");    
    createdItem.setAuctionName(scanner.next());

    System.out.println("----Enter the auctionID----");
    createdItem.setAuctionID(scanner.nextInt());

    System.out.println("----Enter the item startPrice in pound sterling----");
    createdItem.setStartPrice(scanner.nextInt());

    System.out.println("----Enter the buyoutPrice in pound sterling----");
    createdItem.setBuyoutPrice(scanner.nextInt());

    itemSet.add(createdItem);

    System.out.println("---- Item successfully listed ----");
    System.out.println("---- Press 1 to return to auction main menu ----");
    if(scanner.nextInt() == 1){
        sellerChoice();
    }
}
```

I tried writing a for loop that checks if the auctionID is already in existence, however it then doesn't ask the user to input anything at all, and goes straight onto asking for the start price. The loop I tried looked something like this;

```
    for(ItemInfo info : itemSet){
        if(scanner.nextInt() == info.auctionID){
            System.out.println("auctionID already exists!");
        }
    }
```

I am very new to stack overflow and also Java in general, so please inform me if this question is far too long. Any help is greatly appreciated.

MichaelGG

Comment: are you running the client and server in the same jvm?  if so, that is your problem.  they should be running in _separate_ jvm instances.

Comment: I have them running in different command lines and System.exit() ends the server process as well. Rather annoying.

Comment: System.exit() ends the entire JVM. So don't call it from the server code. Call it in the *client.*. You're also taking input from the user in the server, which should also be in the client. Your design is frankly bananas.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @EJP. Could you advise me on how to change my design?

Comment: I have just done exactly that. Call `System.exit()` in the client. Get the user input in the client.